# MySQL populating a new field from parts of existing fields

Tags: mysql

I have a few fields holding paths to images.  I now want to add another field holding the image name.  How can I extract the file name from the full path from another field and update the name into the new field?

this is how i want it to look:

**fields:**

image_thumbnail | image_name

**values:**

http://mysite.com/images/thumbnail/1234.jpg | 1234.jpg

note: image names may have different file extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table
   SET image_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_thumbnail, '/', -1)
     ;
```